# confused between loading json on routes or on models

Tags: json, ember.js

I'm new at emberjs and I'm starting to learn how it works,

what is the difference when specifying the json on routes or on models

```
    model: function() {
    var url = 'https://api.github.com/repos/emberjs/ember.js/pulls';
    return Ember.$.getJSON(url).then(function(data) {
      return data.splice(0, 4);
    });
  },
```

this is how i call the json on routes , now my problem , what is the use of this function

`export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({});`

Answer (score 1):

The `DS.RESTAdapter` is part of [ember-data](/questions/tagged/ember-data). You can use ember-data to load your json from a rest api. It is how ever very opinionated about said api. I don't believe it will work out of the box with the github api you are calling.

If I were you I'd focus on getting to grips with emberjs and when you feel you're getting comfortable with it you can expand your focus to include ember-data.